# Checking and creating a View within MySQL via C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to be able to see if a View already exists within my MySQL database and if it doesn't create one - through c#.  I really could do with a bit of help and a point in the right direction - if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use information_schema to query if a sever object, view in your case, exists. My example code snippet in `C#` is as below.

```
String conn = @"Data Source=myserverName;
       Initial Catalog=myCatalogName;Integrated Security=True";
string cmdStr = "select count(*) from 
      information_schema.views where table_schema = 'mySchemaName' 
      AND table_name = 'MyViewName'";

using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conn))
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdStr, conn);
    conn.Open();
    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
       int count = reader.GetInt32(0);
       if (count == 0)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("View does not exists!");
             MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("Create View myView
             as select
             * from myTable;", conn)
           command.ExecuteNonQuery();

       }
       else if (count == 1)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("View exists!");
       }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Binaya - that's been a big help also - very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use create or replace view view_name as... ?

Comment: I can (but apart from being pretty new to this sort of thing).  If it's already there - I don't want to recreate it.

Comment: database engine recreates the data every time a user queries a view anyway.

Comment: the only difference here is OR REPLACE. if you want to replace an existing view don't put OR REPLACE. Create or replace will create a new one if the view does not exist.

Comment: I wanted to write: If you don't want to replace a view don't put or replace... Typo,  sorry if that was misleading.